# Why would some code that should work NOT work and then START working with nothing changed? xCode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

First question here and can I start by saying how much help this site has been to me and how much I like the way it is laid out!  Can anyone help me with this..

Yesterday I had an issue with a simple bit of code in xcode4.  It was just loading a view from a view controller as part of an if statement.  Being a bit new to iphone development I assumed it was my problem and spent hours trying to figure it out without any luck.

Later that evening a buddy came over and had a look (by this stage I had gone back to my original code with the original issue) he suggested trying the code outside the 'if' statement.  So I just copied the few lines to before the 'if' and commented out the if statement.  Lo and Behold... it worked as it should!

After a couple of 'undo's i ran it again in its original form and... it worked again!  I didn't change a thing!  THREE HOURS!  I could cry!

Anyone know why?  Is there some kind of cache in xcode that gets a bit cranky and if so how do I  reset / clear it?  during my three hours I closed xCode, cleaned several times, shut down the imac more than once...

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4

Comment: Show the code, that is the only way a real answer can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I can't seem to find any of the directories mentioned in daveoncode's link on my iMac.  Does this mean all is good and they are clear (hence gone) or am I being dim and looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if you tried clearing the Build from the build menu - but that's often been an issue for me in previous times.  Always try doing this first.

Comment: I must say I had not tried this.  Going to look for it now and will be sure to do this next time.  Thanks.